# Comparing arrays of IP Ranges and Subnets for Overlaps

Tags: arrays, powershell

Ok, I have two arrays what I'm trying to do is

1. look for overlaps in `array1` (IP Ranges) for first loop,
2. look for overlaps in `array2` (IP Subnets) and then
3. look to see if there is overlap between the ranges and the subnets.

The question been asked here is why when I run this it reports overlap in all which is not the case, eg 192-168.0.1 - 192.168.0.10 (IP range)
    192.168.0.7 - 192.168.0.8 (IP range) overlap each other. However, 10.152.0.100 - 10.152.0.110 (IP range) does not have an overlap with anything so should report with no overlap.

Sample data the `$wmi` returns would be:

```
192-168.0.1 - 192.168.0.10 (IP range)
192.168.0.7 - 192.168.0.8 (IP range)
192.168.0.0 (subnet)
192.168.0.15 - 192.168.0.20 (IP range)
10.152.0.100 - 10.152.0.110 (IP range)
192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.100 (IP range)
```

Code:

```
function get_data
{

    $wmi = gwmi -Namespace "root\sms\site_XXX" -Class sms_boundary -Filter "boundarytype='3'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value #3 = IP Address Range
           $Target= @()

    foreach($i in $wmi)
    {
        $target += $i    
    }

    $wm = gwmi -Namespace "root\sms\site_XXX" -Class sms_boundary -Filter "boundarytype='0'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value #O = IPSubnet
           $Target1= @()

    foreach($i1 in $wm)
    {
        $target1 += $i1    
    }

    foreach($first in $Target)
    {

    if($Target -contains $first)
        {
            write-host "Overlap" $first
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "No Overlap"  $first
        }
    }

    foreach($first1 in $Target1)
    {
    if($Target -contains $first1)
        {
            write-host "Overlap" $first1
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "No Overlap"  $first1
        }    
    }
}

get_data
```

Comment: What is the question? what issue/error are you encountering?

Comment: The question is geared around Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager. Boundaries are a concept within that product. I would recommend sticking with one Configuration Manager Bounary type, rather than mixing IP ranges and IP subnets, by the way.

Comment: 1. I agree with @bnjmn, it's not clear what the problem is. 2. What exactly do you mean by "overlap"? Would you consider the IP ranges `192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.100` and `192.168.1.64 - 192.168.1.128` to be overlapping, or do you just want to compare the elements of the two arrays to find ones that are in both? You can do that with `$target | ?{$target1 -contains $_}`.

Comment: 3. What's the purpose of the first two **foreach** loops? As far as I can tell it's no different than just assigning the entire array, i.e. `$target = $wmi`. Why use the second variable anyway, rather than just use **$wmi** and **$wm** throughout, or assign the results of **gwmi** to **$target** and **$target1**?

Comment: @Trevor, I wish I could be the environment doesn't allow due to the size. The issue is it returns they all overlap, when you can see that is not the case. One loop gathers the IP range, the other loop gathers the IP Subnet.

Comment: question is why does the above code return overlap for all of them, I'm no PS expert but thought my comparing the two arrays it would match where it sees the overlaps accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You loop "ForEach ($first in $target)"

then within that loop you check to see if $first is in $target.
Of course it is since $first is from the foreach loop of $target.
I'm guessing you intended to check 
if ($target1 -contains $first)    ?????

Also, This will not truly check for overlaps.
however the script only looks if exact records match.

10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.10 overlaps with 10.0.0.7 - 10.0.0.8 But the script will not detect that.